# How can we Specify Column type of excel file in xsl

Tags: excel, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

We have a `XSL file` which takes `XML`(Data in `XML` is dynamic,depending on the customer) as input and generates a Excel File, which customers download and fill it and upload back.
One of the column is `customer Id`, where if the customer enters more than 15 digits or more number,it changes to Scientific notation.
I know that customer can format the column and change it to text in excel, which will solve the problem.
But is there a way i can specify the column type in XSL, so that when customer downloads the Sample `Excel` file, the format column as `text` setting will already be applied instead of customer doing it manually.
[Sample Excel File screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoaLS.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example in XML Spreadsheet (2003) with ss:Type="String".

Is that what you mean?

```
<Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="2" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="69"/>
   <Column ss:StyleID="s62" ss:Width="60.75"/>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">1.23456789123456E+17</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">123456789123456789</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
```